# Chrome Extension xmlhttprequest loading incorrect url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am writing a chrome extension and in my extension, I have an XMLHttpRequest that gets JSON data back from the server. I then parse the JSON data looking for URLs.

The problem is that I then call XMLHttpRequest with the URL's I have obtained from the parsed JSON data but for some reason, my URL's have extra information.

The error below is what I get when calling XMLHttpRequest:

GET chrome-extension://kppcidkhcjeehdfhcaliekdbgpbkjahg/%22https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/BldqCmg1rCqffUDXXYjvO_CQ_58pYIfAGCuHY7dTBIw.jpg%22 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I don't understand why there is extra information in my URL. Whenever I output the var that contains the URL string to console.log it outputs correctly: https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/BldqCmg1rCqffUDXXYjvO_CQ_58pYIfAGCuHY7dTBIw.jpg

That above URL is what I want XMLHttpRequest to perform a GET request on, but it seems that the GET request fails because it is not a proper URL.

My initial XMLHttpRequest works when I hard-code the URL, and I have tested hard-coding the URL: https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/BldqCmg1rCqffUDXXYjvO_CQ_58pYIfAGCuHY7dTBIw.jpg
which results in my XMLHttpRequest working fine.

Am I not allowed to perform GET requests on URLs I obtain dynamically from a remote server?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Judging by the error message you're incorrectly using chrome.runtime.getURL which is only for internal files of the extension. Don't use it. Always check the documentation before using an API method for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 `%22` sequences in the faulty url. This is the encoding for a double quote. I think the variable with the url contains a string enclosed in double quotes. When you perform the GET request, it performs a request to the local filesystem of the extension. Hence the request to `chrome-extension://`

One way to diagnose this kind of error, is to console.log the length of the variable containing your url and compare it to what it should be:

```
var real_url = "https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/BldqCmg1rCqffUDXXYjvO_CQ_58pYIfAGCuHY7dTBIw.jpg";
console.log(real_url.length);
console.log(url.length);
```

or console.log the first character of the string:

```
console.log(url.substr(0,1)); // is this a double quote?
```

Try to strip the extra quotes or change the code that's responsible for parsing the json data for the url.

Comment: Yep, you were 100% correct. All I had to do was remove the double quotes and it worked. Thanks so much!